# Scrollable p datatable column width fit to text

Tags: java, primefaces, facelets

Can I define a scrollable datatable where the columns will be as wide as the column text width?

Answer (score 0):

if you have problems with the scroolling and width columns you have to set width attribute of each column (option scrolling = true) (, then the align correctly, we hope :).